# Multiple If Operations at Once

Tags: game-maker-dnd

In my game, I want to have it so that if a chess piece tries to move farther away than a certain distance it won't work. To do this, I need it to have an if statement that works between two numbers, but I can only seem to do above or below a number, not between. Is there a way to do this, or am I going to have to use to if statements?

Comment: Have you tried using expressions? Something like: `distance> = 50 && distance <= 100`

Comment: @bon No, I did not even think of that. I will try that now

Comment: @bon That works. Could you put that as an answer?

Comment: What is the purpose of the DnD in the title?

Comment: @vaill Because of I though that I would have to use a special DnD block, and this is not really a problem in GML.

Comment: Ok, thanks I wasn't aware of that feature!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it direct using the function `point_distance()` or create a variable and give it the value of that distance.

**Code:**

[image]